# Как найти длину перпендикулярных отрезков внутри многоугольника?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, геометрия

> Площадь покрыли перпендикулярными прямыми вида x = a и y = b, где a&b - целые числа. В результате образовалась сетка. Многоугольник состоит из n вершин, которые имеют целочисленные координаты. Нужно найти суммарную длину отрезков сетки, которые лежат строго в заданном многоугольнике (если отрезок совпадает с ребром многоугольника - считать не нужно) Пример правильного ответа дан на рисунке.
>   Входные данные : число n (3 <= n <= 100000), в следующих n строках записаны 2 целых числа (-5 * 10^8 <= x, y <= 5 * 10^8).
>   Вывести одно число(с точностью до 3х знаков) - суммарную длину отрезков сетки, которые лежат строго в заданном многоугольнике.

[image: пример правильного ответа]

Помогите найти метод решения данной задачи пожалуйста.

Comment: Построй описывающий прямоугольник. Сумма длин в нём считается элементарно. Внешнюю для многоугольника область дели на треугольники, у которых 2 катета параллельны осям, а координаты вершин целые - сумма длин в таких тоже считается элементарно. Вычти из первого сумму вторых - остаток и есть ответ.

Comment: Как написать код для описывающего прямоугольника я понимаю, по крайним точкам. Но как написать код чтобы построить треугольники и посчитать сумму их внутренних отрезков нет...

Comment: Ну или наоборот - делай триангуляцию своего многоугольника с теми же ограничениями. Катеты параллельны осям, вершины с целыми координатами. Правда, тут придётся учитывать, является ли катет внутренним или внешним, чтобы случайно два раза не посчитать одно и то же...

Comment: А как построить описывающий многоугольник, например для случая, когда задан прямоугольник у которого все углы скошены? http://www.milking-solutions.com/imagecache/8c3c5488-ab24-42d5-b7cb-908debe7fd3e_120x78.jpg